# How to start docker container in memory?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ram

Is it possible to start container in memory? If yes how I could do it? 
I want to start container with DB inside (Postgresql) for testing purpose.

P.S. I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what do you mean by in-memory? Of course you can have a Postgres DB container but dont understand your in-memory statement.

Comment: My pc has a lot of RAM, I want to start container in RAM

Comment: Docker containers are isolated processes. and like a regular program they will have a in memory component, but it will be interacting with the disk as well. Where will the Postgres DB files go? they need to be on the Disk.

Comment: Everything inside a docker container, I need this for perfomance

Comment: Try looking at H2 if you need a inmemory DB.

Comment: No!!!!!! I need Postgresql if I can use h2 I did it!

Comment: You need to read about Docker, Postgres and processes on a OS in general. And then probably you will arrive at your answer. Also do update the Question with what have you tried till now so that maybe someone who has a has an answer to this can take a look at it.

Comment: Then create a ramdisk, map the postgres db volume to there.